# Recyclerview move to penultimate position when the list is update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, mutablelivedata, android-diffutils

Currently i have the next config.

`RecyclerView` + `MutableLiveData` + `DiffUtils`

The behavior is:

When i move to the last position and update the list, the RecyclerView move automatically to penultimate item, but only happen with the last position

Answer (score 0):

```
lst.insert(-1, lst.pop(0))
```

So it follows this syntax:

```
lst.insert(new_index, lst.pop(old-index))
```

Or if you don't know where `Recycler View` is:

```
lst.insert(-1, lst.pop(lst.index("Recycler View")))
```